# What is Converting circular to JSON error

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to get data from backend which consists of an object in which a URL is present and what I am trying to do with the received URL is to change the URL of my react App . Here is how my object looks   :

```
const obj = {
  id: 'fd723',
  url: 'https://someURL'
}
```

Here is my code from frontend :

```
    const checkoutHandler = async (btnValue) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/chec", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        withCredentials: true,
        credentials: "same-origin",
        body: btnValue,
      });
      console.log(res.data);
    const url = res.data.url;
    console.log(url);
    window.location.href = url;
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("Error" , e);
  }
```

Here is how I am sending the data from my express backend :

```
console.log(data);//which successfully shows me the data
return res.json(data)
```

Comment: Did you check the network tools? Is the request successful? Does it fail? Does it time out? Is the *network* request finished successfully but handling the result fails?

Comment: Nope , there is no request related to backend in my network tab .

Comment: My post request is successful but not receiving the data from backend

Comment: Would be better to check response on `postman` or any other kind of tool first?

Comment: yup , I got the error , it is saying converting circular structure to json when I followed answer by @LaurentDhont

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `res.json` method in order to send the valid response.
https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json

It also sets the proper Content-Type header on your response and stringifies your JSON automatically.

So: `res.json(data);`

My guess is that axios doesn't recognize your response as a JSON.

Comment: And how should I access the url thing returned from backend in my frontend

Comment: @Dodo96 The same way you did in the example: res.url, Can you show the output of console.log(res); please?

Comment: When I console res ,  I recieve the error in console that : Converting circular structure to json

Comment: @Dodo96 Did you send it with with res.json? Can you share the full code please

Comment: @Dodo96 I meant the code of your back-end. All you do before res.json(data)